# Pythonのsocket通信のfromとimportについて

Tags: python, socket

Pythonのfromとimportの使い方について質問です。

```
from socket import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

だとエラーになって
AttributeError: type object 'socket' has no attribute 'gethostbyname'
というメッセージが出ます。

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

だとエラーにならないのは何故でしょうか？
`from socket import socket`の部分を残したまま、エラーを出さないコードにするにはどうすれば良いですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from socket import socket
```

これは、socketモジュールにあるsocketオブジェクト（この場合は関数オブジェクト）を現在の名前空間に取り込んでいます。
以下と同義です

```
import socket
socket = socket.socket
```

`socket.gethostbyname()` は socketモジュールにある `gethostbyname` 関数オブジェクトを呼び出すことを意図したコードです。このため、 `from socket import socket` と書いてしまうと、現在の名前空間にあるのは socketモジュールではなく、socket関数オブジェクトのため、「socket関数オブジェクトにgethostbyname属性がない」というエラーになります。

```
AttributeError: type object 'socket' has no attribute 'gethostbyname'
```

それがこのエラーです。

> `from socket import socket` の部分を残したまま、エラーを出さないコードにするにはどうすれば良いですか？

以下の様に書くことが出来ます

```
from socket import gethostbyname, gethostname
gethostbyname(gethostname())
```